# What is this syntax structure and how does it work?

Tags: php

I'm not sure how the comparison operation of the array node works in relation to the assignment of 'true' to the same array node.  Is this some alternate usage of the Ternary syntax?  Either an explanation or a link to the PHP reference (I don't even know how to search for this) would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

```
// RESOLVE myvar TO BOOLEAN
$atts['myvar'] = 'true' == $atts['myvar'];
```

Comment: The comment tells you what the code is doing: `resolve myvar to boolean`, although it’s not resolving it to a _true_ boolean, merely the string `true`. A horrible bit of code if you ask me. `settype($atts['myvar'], 'boolean')` would be better.

Comment: @MartinBean It properly resolves to regular boolean. It's far from best code I've seen but I'd not call it horrible either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this like that:

```
$atts['myvar'] = ('true' == $atts['myvar']);
```

(saving on brackets is never worth a penny). When run, it will compare actual content of `$atts['myvar']` with **string** `true` (4 letters) and then overwrite `$atts['myvar']` with result of the comparison, which will be **boolean** by then. If it equals to string "true" then result is boolean `true`, for anything else it will become boolean `false`. In other words, it converts "string boolean" to regular boolean.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise response.  This helps a great deal.